# How can I link an existing resource to cloudformation stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I have an existing dynamodb table deployed in AWS. And I am creating a cloudformation stack to include this table. The create failed because the table already exist. Is there a way for me to link the dynamodb table to cloudformation stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Bringing existing resources into CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html).

> During an import operation, you create a change set that imports your
> existing resources into a stack or creates a new stack from your
> existing resources. You provide the following during import:
>
> 1. A template that describes the entire stack.
> 2. Identifiers for the resources to import.